# filled map + location map in R

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, geolocation, rworldmap

Rephrasing the question...I am preparing report and one part of it is spatial viz.

I have 2 datasets. First(Scores) is countries with their scores. Second one (Locations) is exact longitude and latitude that refers to an exact location inside those countries. Let that be examples:

```
Scores = data.frame( Country = c("Lebanon","UK","Chille"), Score =c(1,3.5,5))
Locations = data.frame(Location_Name = c("London Bridge", "US Embassy in Lebanon" , "Embassy of Peru in Santiago"),
                       LONG = c(-0.087749, 35.596614, -70.618236), 
                       LAT = c(51.507911, 33.933586, -33.423285))
```

What i want to achieve is get filled map of the world (in my dataset i have every country) and color inside of its boundouries with the Score (Scores$Score) on continous scale.
On top of that I would like to add pins, bubbles or whatever marker of Locations from Locations dataframe.

So my desired outcome would be combination of this view:
[image: Filled map]

and this view:

[image: Location map]

Ideally i would like also to be able to draw 2km radius around the Locations from Locations data.frame also.

I know to do them separately but cant seem to achieve it on one nice clean map.

I really appreciate any help or tips on this, got stuck for whole day on that one

Comment: Hi! Can you share a [reproducible example](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) of your problem? And what do you mean by exact geolocations?

Comment: rephraes the quesiton :)

Comment: Would you accept a solution using other packages like [tmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/vignettes/tmap-getstarted.html)?

Comment: Ofcourse, any approach that does the job :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @agila you can use the `tmap` package.

First merge your `Scores` data with `World` so you can fill countries based on `Scores` data. Note that your `Country` column should match the `name` in World exactly when merging.

You will need to use `st_as_sf` from `sf` package to make your `Locations` an `sf` object to add to map.

`tm_dots` can show points. An alternative for bubbles is `tm_bubbles`.

```
library(tmap)
library(sf)

data(World)

Scores = data.frame(Country = factor(c("Mexico","Brazil","Chile"), levels = levels(World$name)), 
                    Score =c(1,3.5,5))
Locations = data.frame(Location_Name = c("Rio de Janeiro", "US Embassy in Lebanon" , "Embassy of Peru in Santiago"),
                       LONG = c(-43.196388, 35.596614, -70.618236), 
                       LAT = c(-22.908333, 33.933586, -33.423285))

map_data <- merge(World, Scores, by.x = "name", by.y = "Country", all = TRUE)

locations_sf <- st_as_sf(Locations, coords = c('LONG', 'LAT'))

tm_shape(map_data) +
  tm_polygons("Score", palette = "-Blues") +
  tm_shape(locations_sf) +
  tm_dots(size = .1)
```

**Map**

[image: world map with filled countries and points of interest]

Comment: And for the buffers you can check [st_buffer](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/geos_unary.html) or just increase the dot size if you don't care of the buffer size.

Comment: This is what i was looking for! Thanks a lot!